# Cannot find function getName in object function getContinuationToken()

Tags: google-apps-script

I inherited some code for a Google document sharing site. Google sunsetted the docslist class and I converted over to driveapp. The following function checks if any files are added. I have a basic understanding of the code and do not understand what is causing the error.

The following function does not work. Cannot find function getName in object function getContinuationToken()

Here is the function:

```
function checkDocs(){

  try {
var pageFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3e2-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
var filesAdded = new Array();
var counter = 0;
var pageFiles = pageFolder.getFiles();
var blank = new Array(); //extra for function
var type = "FILE";

  // Logger.log(pageFiles)

for (var i = 0; i < pageFiles.length; i++) {
  if (!inProperties(pageFiles[i].getName(), pageFiles[i].getFileType().toString(), type)) {
    filesAdded[counter] = pageFiles[i];
    counter++;
  }
}

if (filesAdded.length > 0) {  
  thereAreUpdates = true;
  docWasAdded = true;
  additioned(filesAdded, blank, type);
}

deletedDocs = checkDeleted(pageFiles);
if (deletedDocs.length > 0) {
 thereAreUpdates = true;
 docWasRemoved = true;
   }

  } catch (e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxxx@xxxxx.com", "Doc Share Error - Doc", e.message);
  }
}
```

The function inProperties is this

```
//checking to see if the file or link is in the database
function inProperties(first,second,type) { //file: name,type ... link: name,link

  var keys = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys(); 
  var exists = false;

  if (keys.length > 0) {
if (type == "FILE") {
  for (i in keys) {
    if (keys[i] == (second + " - " + first)) {
      exists = true;
    }
  }
}
if (type == "LINK") {
  for (i in keys) {
    if (keys[i] == ("link - " + second)) {
      exists = true;
    }
  }
}
  }

  if (exists) {
return true;
  } else {
  addition(first,second,type);
  return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks very much I changed the code and now it gets farther but still has an error.

When debugging it gets to the filesAdded line and then goes right to catch. The debugger shows filesAdded []  counter = 0.0 and I don't see a value for i. There are correct values for thisFileName, thisFileType and Type.

```
if (!inProperties(thisFileName, thisFileType, type)) {
  filesAdded[counter] = pageFiles[i];
  counter++;
```

Comment: What does `inProperties` refer to on line 14 of the function?

Comment: I've added the in Properties function

Comment: There have been reports of issues with the `PropertiesService`.  So, if your code was working, and now suddenly has problems without any changes, I'd be suspicious of the `PropertiesService`.

Comment: The best thing to do, is step through the code with the debugger.  See documentation:  [TroubleShooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `hasNext()` method with the FileIterator that is returned from `getFiles()`.

This example code is directly from the documentation:

```
// Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

You don't need to use a while loop, if for example, you only wanted one file.  But in your case, it looks like you are getting multiple files.

So, I changed your code to this:

```
try {
  var pageFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID HERE');
  var filesAdded = new Array();
  var counter = 0;
  var pageFiles = pageFolder.getFiles();
  var blank = new Array(); //extra for function
  var type = "FILE";

  // Logger.log(pageFiles)
  var thisFileType = "";
  var thisFileName = "";

   while (pageFiles.hasNext()) {
     var file = pageFiles.next();
     Logger.log(file.getName());
     thisFileName = file.getName();
     thisFileType = file.getMimeType();

    if (!inProperties(thisFileName, thisFileType, type)) {
      filesAdded[counter] = pageFiles[i];
      counter++;
    }
  }
```

There is no `getFileType()` method of the files class, you need to use `getMimeType()`